# Changing AppBarLayout's background color based on recycler scroll with no collapse

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

This seems like it should be pretty straight forward, but I haven't been able to find a way to make this work without using a collapsing toolbar.  Typically for something like this I'd create a custom behavior and use the offset changed event for animations or changes.

However for this layout, I don't want any thing to collapse.  I just want a toolbar layout at the top, a recycler view underneath, and when recycler view is at its 0 position to have a transparent background, and when its scroll at all it should have a colored background.

It looks like behavior events don't trigger on items inside of the of the AppBarLayout, only on items that are direct child of coordinator.  And I can't set a custom behavior on the AppBarLayout itself.

Any tips on how to do this, or should I drop the coordinator layout for this case and just use a normal scroll binding event on the recycler view? Very basic XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:elevation="0dp">

       <include layout="@layout/a_tool_bar"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Error when trying to apply a custom behavior to the appbarlayout.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: This graph contains cyclic dependencies
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.DirectedAcyclicGraph.dfs(DirectedAcyclicGraph.java:179)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.DirectedAcyclicGraph.dfs(DirectedAcyclicGraph.java:187)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.DirectedAcyclicGraph.dfs(DirectedAcyclicGraph.java:187)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.DirectedAcyclicGraph.getSortedList(DirectedAcyclicGraph.java:167)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.prepareChildren(CoordinatorLayout.java:691)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:739)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:805)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:716)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23169)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2718)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1572)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1855)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: "And I can't set a custom behavior on the AppBarLayout itself." – Why's that?

Comment: I get a circular dependency issue, i'm assuming because of the dependency of the recyclerview's appbar_scrolling_view_behavior?  One sec, i'll recreate and post the error here.

Comment: OK, I'm really not sure if I'm following your description of the desired behavior correctly, but I was able to effect a simple color switch, when the `RecyclerView` is at its very top, by subclassing `AppBarLayout.Behavior`. It doesn't report an explicit dependency on the `RecyclerView`, which I think might've been the issue with your `Behavior`. Anyhoo, here's my very simple test: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10rCAyBgIxk8yEX9dyAyKwvGS42ux0T4u/view?usp=drivesdk. I've got IDE problems, atm, so I was testing with the old design library. You might need some tweaks for androidx/material.

Comment: I tried something similar before, what element are you attaching this behavior to that is causing it to trigger consistently on scroll?  I ran into issues where I couldn't get it to trigger for all scrolls.  Thanks for the help

Comment: It's on the `AppBarLayout`. It's just overriding its default behavior to catch all vertical nested scrolls – normally `onStartNestedScroll()` checks for a scrolling/collapsing child, too – and to do only the color switch when the nested scroller hits/leaves its very top – `onNestedScroll()` is normally resizing the `AppBarLayout`. Mind you, I tested this only with the basic layout shown above. I was mainly checking for the circular dependency snag.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll give it a shot today and let you know.  Appreciate all the follow up.  Thanks!